# Is serial modem routine written on the Arduino Leonardo bootloader?

Tags: serial, arduino-leonardo, bootloader

I'm starting with Leonardo and I'm a bit confuse about the serial modem function. As you know on boot the Leonardo for the first 8 seconds wait for a program on the USB port and then it goes in serial modem mode while my program runs.

I'm designing a consumer product (open source) and I will like to make some modifications to my board in order to make it more friendly:

1. On boot it has to go into *programming mode* only if a jumper is set. Otherwise it goes directly into *serial modem*.
2. I need to change to *modem name*, instead of:
   [image]
3. Have the operating system pickup the serial modem with no drivers request.

For 1 and 2, is it possible? should I try to modify Caterina or it will be easier to work with [Optiboot](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot)? Number 3 works already in linux distributions, but in Windows some pcs ask for drivers are, and even worse, some windows 64bits + usb3 requires some minors hacks to pick up the Leonardo serial drivers, is it possible to improve? Ideally I want the board to be connected to a PC/Mac/Linux and get configured as a serial com with no user intervention.

I think this are questions that every person trying to create a consumer product with Arduino needs to answer before producing the actual product. So, and resources, references and *where to start* guides will help me and other people in the community.

Comment: Sounds like you need to be using the stock Atmel '32U4 firmware instead of any Arduino bootloader. Also, [here's USB in a Nutshell](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml) so that you can handle items 2 and 3.